# Why can't I malloc request memory and assign a value in a function using a string, but a string in a struct can?

Tags: c, struct, malloc

why it wrong
`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void func(char* dest, const char* src)
{
    dest = malloc(strlen(src) + 1);
    strcpy(dest, src);
}

int main()
{
    char* name0;
    char* name1 = "Jam";

    func(name0, name1);
    puts(name0);
    
    free(name0);
    return 0;
}
```

`but`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct st
{
    char* name;
};

void func(struct st* st1, const struct st* st2);

int main(void)
{
    struct st name0, name1;
    name1.name = "Jam";

    func(&name0, &name1);

    puts(name0.name);

    free(name0.name);
    name0.name = NULL;

    exit(0);
}

void changename(struct st* st1, const struct st* st2)
{
    st1->name = malloc(strlen(st2->name) + 1);
    if(st1->name == NULL)
        exit(1);
    strcpy(st1->name, st2->name);
}
```

`
is right

#I tried to use the first method to explain why the second method makes sense and why the second method solves the problem, but the first one reports an error and doesn't give me the answer I want.
#Why can't I malloc request memory and assign a value in a function using a string, but a string in a struct can?

Comment: The `char* name0;` you passed from `main` is unaltered: `func` is working with a *copy* of it, and immediately overwrites it. The memory allocation is left 'dangling' and cannot be accessed in `main` or `free`d.

Comment: parameters are passed by value, pointers are no exception

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but why is it possible under struct？

Comment: Don't make is work so hard; explain what is "wrong" in the first example - compiler diagnostic or runtime error for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the pointer to the character pointer by reference not by value.

```
void func(char** dest, const char* src)
{
    *dest = malloc(strlen(src) + 1);
    strcpy(*dest, src);
}
```

Comment: ...and change the call-point in `main` to `func(&name0, name1)`. It's important.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I know this, I just don't know why it can be done under struct, in fact the difference is just under struct isn't it, it's not fair

Answer (score 0):

Other errors that might be present aside, the big difference between those two is an additional level of indirection.

Consider this struct

```
struct foo { 
     int * x;
};
```

And now this two functions:

```
void f1(int* a) {  a = nullptr; }

void f2(foo* f) { f.x. = nullptr;  f = nullptr;}
```

When `f1` is called, modifying the local copy `a` has no effect on the pointer passed by the caller:

```
int i = 0;
int* ptr = &i;
f1(ptr);                // a copy of ptr is made
assert( ptr == &i);     // ptr still points to i
```

The same is true for the pointer passed to `f2`. Modifying `f` inside `f2` has no effect on the pointer passed by the caller. Though, you can modify what `f` points to in `f2`, and that is visible to the caller.

```
foo fo;
int i = 0;
fo.x = &i;
foo* foptr = &fo;
f2(foptr);           // a copy of foptr is made, it also points to fo

assert( fo.x == nullptr);     // the function did modif fo
assert( foptr->x == nullptr); 

assert( foptr == &fo );       // same as above, foptr still points to fo
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I seem to have a little understanding, I'm thinking carefully about some of your words

Answer (score 0):

In one case, you have `func(name0, name1)`. In the other, you have `func(&name0, &name1)`.

A function cannot change the value passed to it. When you pass `name0`, the function cannot change `name0`. It receives only a copy of its values. Similarly, when you pass `&name0`, the function cannot change the value of `&name0`. However, that value points to an object. The function can change the object it points to.

When you pass `&name0`, and the function executes `st1->name =…`, it changes the `name` inside the object that `st1` points to, which is `name0`.

If you call the first function the same way as the second, `func(&name0, &name1)`, then the function will be passed pointers to `name0` and `name1` instead of being passed their values. Then you need to change `func` to match:

```
void func(char **dest, const char **src)
{
    *dest = malloc(strlen(*src) + 1);
    strcpy(*dest, *src);
}
```

With these changes, the function operates on the things that its parameters `dest` and `src` point to instead of on the values in `dest` and `src`.

(It is not necessary to change the `src` parameter in the call and the function definition, since the source object does not need to be changed. I changed it only to match your second function.)